# Книга Философия джавы

Tags: java

Сам я прочитал страниц 400 сперва, там как раз все самое банальное описывалось, Я думал вот я какой умник прочел и уже даже кажется синтаксис умею писать джавовский.... Потом забил на пол года почти на эту книгу, с мыслями я программист ниибаться, пора спринг учить, а то что осталось в книге наверное легкотня потом прочту на досуге. Начал читать по спрингу книгу, и пару моментов меня в ступор ввело, например про Макито встретилось там.... Потом я посмотрел по оглавлению и увидел что в книге Экеля почти под конец есть о этом Макито "пару страниц" ... Ну решил пришло время для книги. И тут то я понял что я даже еще пол книги не дочитал, и дальше менее тривиальные вещи обсуждаются... В общем это какойто капец. + работа получается что я усваиваю очень мало материала. Вот щас опять встает вопрос. Может ну его нфиг, прочесть про те вещи которые меня интересуют. А все что останется пока оставить. НАпример мене интересен свинг и тот самый макито, ну может еще система ввода вывода и лямды.... А другое все пропустить может!?(сейчас я на 580 странице из 1150)

(Прошу взять на заметку, что те кто читали книгу онлайн могут не правильно себе представить обьем реальной книги, потому что многие говорят что читали а потом дают ссылку и я вижу там максимум 100 страниц самого банального текста про джаву, в общем сильно урезанную версию)

Тут и назрвевают вопросы:

- Кто реально прочитал эту книгу?
- Сколько времени это у вас заняло?
- Все ли примеры вы делали?
- Ну и    может пару советов...

Comment: Прочитайте по этой ссылке. Там как раз про чтение книг найдете.  http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-7-0-00000012-000-0-0-1461423512

Comment: Что касается вашего вопроса, то, скорей всего, он будет закрыт, так как вопрос слишком общий и базируется на персональных мнениях.:)